# CMake cannot find GLEW (installed with apt)

Tags: c++, cmake

Good morning/afternoon/evening,

I am currently trying to train myself in CMake, which is, as many would say, a real pain. My current problem is the following: I would simply like to include the GLEW library in my little test project. I installed GLEW using `apt-get install libglew-dev`. Consequently, `libGLEW.so` is in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`. My `CMakeLists.txt` looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(test_dcmtk)

find_library(GLEW glew REQUIRED)

if (${GLEW} STREQUAL GLEW-NOTFOUND)
    message(FATAL_ERROR "GLEW not found !")
else()
    message(STATUS "GLEW found as ${GLEW}")
endif ()

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)

add_executable(test_dcmtk main.cpp)
```

I believe this looks right... But as you might have guessed, this does not allow me to find the library which does not make any sense.
I tried to append `/usr/` path to the `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable, hoping that it would help but it did not. As I am a beginner in CMake, I have trouble understanding where the issue might be... YouTube tutorials have shown me that this CMake script should work but it does not.

If anyone had an idea, I would be very grateful !

Comment: `find_library(GLEW glew REQUIRED)` will only search for the library named `glew`. E.g. `libglew.so`. It cannot find the file `libGLEW.so`, because it corresponds to the name `GLEW`. If you want to search both names, then specify them both: ``find_library(GLEW NAMES glew GLEW REQUIRED)``.

Comment: try to use upper case library name? `find_library(GLEW GLEW REQUIRED)`

Comment: BTW, what is wrong in using **ready-made module** for find GLEW: [find_package(GLEW)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindGLEW.html).

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. It worked. Silly mistake as always. There's nothing wrong with using ready-made module. I just try to include this library as an exercise for more complex libraries to include and therefore am testing all possible options. Once again, thank you all for your answers.

Comment: The fact that you supplied REQUIRED makes it impossible to reach the "GLEW not found" message. And you're definitely going to need a `target_link_libraries` somewhere in there...